# Is it possible to remove the name of the list on a SharePoint view-page?

Tags: list, listview, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint site with one list with several views. In the top of the view-sites is the name of the list (Tasks) and below the name of the view. Is it possible to get rid of the name of the list (Tasks) and only have the name of the view at the top?

I have tried to edit the webpart and remove the title, but that is the title of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for SharePoint 2013: 
Add a scripteditor to the page and add the following script

```html
<script language="javascript">

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideBrandingsuite");

function HideBrandingsuite()

{

document.getElementById('pageTitle').style.visibility = 'hidden';

} 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know each view for a list is its own page. Each of those pages will be referencing the Title of the list. See photo of all the views that this example task list has.

[Example of how each view is an aspx page under parent list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgreT.png)

You have a couple options.

1. Through SharePoint designer edit each of the views and remove the references to the task list title.
2. Add a Code Snippet web part and add css that will hide the Task title on load.

[Example of how to place CSS in code snippet web part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/912H2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following script to hide the list name in a view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").getElementsByTagName('a')[1].innerHTML="";
</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks - it didn't work for me, i think it might be because we're still on SP2013 - it did however lead me to a solution that works for me, that I'll post as answer